# data.table filter doesn't work in with()?

Tags: r, data.table

I am filetering a data.table based on another data.table, and it gives a very odd result.
please advise,

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

set.seed(100)
xA = data.table(A = letters[1:4], B = sample(1:1000))
xB = data.table(A = letters[1:4], B = sample(1:100))


with(xA[30], {
  sprintf(" xA A = %s B = %s", A, B) %>% print
  xB[A == A]$A %>% print
  print("")
  xB[A == "b"]$A %>% print
})

#[1] " xA A = b B = 322"
#  [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "a" "b" "c" "d" "a" "b" "c" "d" "a" "b" "c" "d" "a" "b" "c" "d" "a" "b" "c" #"d" "a" "b" "c" "d" "a" "b" "c" "d" "a" "b"
# [35] "c" "d" "a" "b" "c" "d" "a" "b" "c" "d" "a" "b" "c" "d" "a" "b" "c" "d" "a" "b" "c" "d" "a" #"b" "c" "d" "a" "b" "c" "d" "a" "b" "c" "d"
# [69] "a" "b" "c" "d" "a" "b" "c" "d" "a" "b" "c" "d" "a" "b" "c" "d" "a" "b" "c" "d" "a" "b" "c" #"d" "a" "b" "c" "d" "a" "b" "c" "d"

#[1] " xA A = b B = 322"
# [1] "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" #"b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b"
```

With the toy code, it shall give a result of all `b` as the second result, but it gave everything as first printout. How come? Thanks for advice.

Comment: The output you are getting is same if t you do `xB[A == A]$A` outside `with`. Since `data.table` does not need `$` to refer to column names it doesn't know that `A` you are referring to should come from `xA` or `xB`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you just look at the statement

```
xB[A == A]
```

How do you know which is a column name and which is a variable name? In this case, data.table just assumes you want all rows where column A is equal to itself (which is all of them. Try using a differnt variable name

```
with(xA[30], {
  sprintf(" xA A = %s B = %s", A, B) %>% print
  a <- A
  xB[A == a]$A
})
```

Comment: exactly! I should have to assign a variable for the condition.